# Оптимизация функции Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

ревьюер сказал что нужно оптимизировать функцию но я не могу понять как это сделать

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name: str, tasks: str, penalties: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.tasks = int(tasks)
        self.penalties = int(penalties)

    def __lt__(self, prev: 'Participant') -> bool:
        if self.tasks == prev.tasks:
            if self.penalties == prev.penalties:
                return self.name < prev.name
            return self.penalties < prev.penalties
        return self.tasks > prev.tasks

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

а комментарий таков:

> Вместо `if'-ов советую просто сравнить кортежи

только я вот не пойму как это сделать если у меня на if завязаны return'ы

Comment: нет, я конечно могу сравнить кортежи и получить с них True или False но всеравно мне дальше по функции нужно будет применить if ( if True...)

Comment: Вы для начала объясните свою реализацию, с комментариями в скрипте. Потом покажите вызов, а то не понятно почему речь идёт о кортежах, если вы сравниваете тип int между собой.

Comment: По моему текст "советую просто сравнить кортежи" надо читать дословно, `(1, 2) > (1, 3) =>
False` и 
`(1, 2) > (1, 1) => True` при сравнении кортежей сначала сравнивается первый элемент, и если они равны, то сравнивается второй и так далее. Ваши if делают то же самое, следовательно можно собрать все нужные для сравнения поля в правильном порядке в кортежи и сравнить их. Там правда у вас знаки <> разные, так что внимательно смотрите что в какой кортеж положить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать так:

1. Избавляемся от `if self.penalties == prev.penalties:`, `return self.penalties < prev.penalties` - так как знаки сравнения `name` и `penalties` одинаковы (`<`) просто сравнием кортежи `(penalties, name)`:

```
def __lt__(self, prev: 'Participant') -> bool:
    if self.tasks == prev.tasks:
        return (self.penalties, self.name) < (prev.penalties, prev.name)
    return self.tasks > prev.tasks
```

2. Избавляемся от `if self.tasks == prev.tasks:`, `return self.tasks > prev.tasks` - так как знаки сравнения `(penalties, name)` и `tasks` различаются, то меняем местами `self.tasks` и `prev.tasks`:

```
def __lt__(self, prev: 'Participant') -> bool:
    return (prev.tasks, self.penalties, self.name) < (self.tasks, prev.penalties, prev.name)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение, все понял, спасибо!